# Is making a public comment about a girl's breasts illegal?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech, colorado, juvenile-law

From a Washington Post's article about Columbine HS:

> A similar event happened at a Columbine wrestling match at Arvada High
>   School. Pyne, "in front of everyone," said Harwick, broadcast to all
>   within earshot: " **'Her breasts are getting bigger.'** They're laughing
>   -- the jocks were." She told Coach Place; he told her to sit on the other side of the gym.
>
> She then went to a woman at a concession stand, who called the Arvada
>   police. The officer issued Pyne a ticket. Because he was a juvenile,
>   court records are not available, but Harwick said he **pleaded guilty
>   and paid a $50 fine**.

While it's obviously in poor taste, I'm surprised that a comment like "Her breasts are getting bigger" is actually illegal. What laws were being broken, and might not such speech be protected by the Constitution?

Comment: What was crime the ticket a charge for?

Comment: That statement sure doesn't seem like it would warrant a criminal charge. I'd like to know the answer to this one as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a witness willing to break their silence, we will probably never be certain. It is possible that this was [harassment](https://library.municode.com/co/arvada/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PTIICOOR_CH62OF_ARTIIMIOF_S62-32ASHA) (current ordinance, not 1999 – version in force at that time not available), defined in Arvada if one has the intent to annoy (etc.) and "Repeatedly insults, taunts, challenges, or makes communications in offensively coarse language to another in a manner likely to provoke a violent or disorderly response" (the ["record"](http://vanessawest.tripod.com/columbine-4.html) indicates that there was a pattern of such conduct). We don't actually know that he was fined (hearsay...).